# Can I register a block etc in Minecraft after start (ex. while user is in settings)?

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I think the title makes it pretty clear but:

I want to register a block etc in Minecraft but after the Minecraft client has fully loaded (ie. after startup; pre-init; init; post-init etc ...)

Comment: The answer is very likely "maybe".  However, the  follow-up question to this is, "what have you done to attempt to do this, and what error did you run into when you attempted it?"

Answer (score 0):

## No

Do not conditionally register blocks and items, this is a great way to corrupt saved worlds. The item and block registries are locked after startup for a *reason.*

If you want your items to be conditional, make them *unobtainable:* do not register any recipes and do not show the items in the creative tab.